# Forcing users to save as a certain filename, weird bug

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a weird bug with this code. The code forces the user to save the file under a particular filename. This works, however the first time I press save as, the file is not saved! But when I press save a second time it works!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strName As String
    Dim lFind As Long
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim NamePath As String

   If SaveAsUI = True Then

       cancel = True
       With Application

            .EnableEvents = False
            NamePath = .GetSaveAsFilename
            strName = Mid(NamePath, InStrRev(NamePath, "\", -1, vbTextCompare) + 1, 256)
            NamePath = Left(NamePath, InStrRev(NamePath, "\"))

            If NamePath = "False" Then
                .EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf Left(strName, 6) <> "MCFR25" Or strName = "MCFR25 Template.xlsm" Then
                NewName = InputBox("The filename """ & strName & """ is incorrect" & vbNewLine & _
                           "The filename either does not start with MCFR25 or is MCFR25 Template.xlsm" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                            "Please input a name below starting with MCFR25" & vbNewLine & _
                            "For instance, MCFR25 xyz" & vbNewLine & _
                            "Do not include any extension, i.e., .xlsm", "Rename", "MCFR25")
                If NewName = vbNullString Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If Left(NewName, 6) = "MCFR25" Then
                    strName = NewName & ".xlsm"
                End If

                Me.SaveAs NamePath & strName
               .EnableEvents = True

            End If
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried stepping trough it with the debugger?

Comment: Indeed, I have and the trigger seems to not always click in, it is quite random!

Comment: So sometime it don't go into the `Before_Save` at all?

Comment: @litelite that would appear to be the case.

Comment: Do you have any other code that might disable the events (`.EnableEvents = False`) ?

Comment: No that is the only instance of .enableevents = false in the code. Or are you saying I should try using an alternative approach to disabling the events, see the thing is the save box appears and when I type in the name it appears to not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120718/discussion-between-litelite-and-lowpar).

Comment: @litelite sorry I only saw your request for chat now, bummer, anyway you were correct. It was incorrectly using .EnableEvents that caused the problem!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only save the file if the filename is wrong. You will need to add an else like this so you will also save the file when the name is correct.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strName As String
    Dim lFind As Long
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim NamePath As String

   If SaveAsUI = True Then

       cancel = True
       With Application

            .EnableEvents = False
            NamePath = .GetSaveAsFilename
            strName = Mid(NamePath, InStrRev(NamePath, "\", -1, vbTextCompare) + 1, 256)
            NamePath = Left(NamePath, InStrRev(NamePath, "\"))

            If NamePath = "False" Then
                .EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf Left(strName, 6) <> "MCFR25" Or strName = "MCFR25 Template.xlsm" Then
                NewName = InputBox("The filename """ & strName & """ is incorrect" & vbNewLine & _
                           "The filename either does not start with MCFR25 or is MCFR25 Template.xlsm" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                            "Please input a name below starting with MCFR25" & vbNewLine & _
                            "For instance, MCFR25 xyz" & vbNewLine & _
                            "Do not include any extension, i.e., .xlsm", "Rename", "MCFR25")
                If NewName = vbNullString Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If Left(NewName, 6) = "MCFR25" Then
                    strName = NewName & ".xlsm"
                End If

                Me.SaveAs NamePath & strName
               .EnableEvents = True
            Else
                 Me.SaveAs NamePath & strName
                 .EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man, I did kind of figure out that I had the end if in the wrong location, but your answer did the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the format to .xlsm

```
Me.SaveAs NamePath & strName, FileFormat:=52
```

Comment: excel would still save it. It would only show an error when the user would try to open the file. OP says that the file isnot saved at all

Comment: I was getting an error, saying 'you can't save this as it isn't a macro enabled workbook' Forcing the format cleared that and it saves every time for me, ran it a dozen times.

Comment: However, opening a saved workbook with the MCFR25 xxx format no longer triggers the save code.